# Мне нужно сократить имя и отчество до одной буквы. Как это возможно сделать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Я новичок в python, извините за глупый вопрос. Мне нужно сократить имя и отчество до одной буквы. Как это возможно сделать?

```
k = {0: 'Иванов Иван Иванович',
     1: 'Николаев Николай Николаевич'}
```

То что должно получиться

```
k = {0: 'Иванов И. И.',
     1: 'Николаев Н. Н.'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попытался извратиться через регулярные выражения:

```
import re
replace_match = lambda x: '{} {}. {}.'.format(x[1], x[2][0], x[3][0])

for key, text in k.items():
    new_text = re.sub(r'(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)', replace_match, text)
    k[key] = new_text

print(k)  # {0: 'Иванов И. И.', 1: 'Николаев Н. Н.'}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in k:
  a = k[i].split(' ')
  a[1] = a[1][0] + '.'
  a[2] = a[2][0] + '.'
  k[i] = ' '.join(a)
```

Comment: Элементы списка `a` - уже строки. `map(str, k[i])` - явно лишнее. Просто `k[i] = '  '.join(a)`

Comment: Не заметил. Просто привык так писать. Сейчас исправлю, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
k = {0: 'Иванов Иван Иванович',
     1: 'Николаев Николай Николаевич'}

for key, value in k.items():
    _l = value.split()
    k[key] = f'{_l[0]} {_l[1][0]}. {_l[2][0]}.'

print(k)  # {0: 'Иванов И. И.', 1: 'Николаев Н. Н.'}
```

С индексами не очень красиво смотрится, можно и так:

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_first_symbol = itemgetter(0)

for key, value in k.items():
    surname, *flname = value.split()
    k[key] = '{} {}. {}.'.format(surname, *map(get_first_symbol, flname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один чуть другой вариант для разнообразия:

```
k = {0: 'Иванов Иван Иванович',
     1: 'Николаев Николай Николаевич'}

def fio(full_name):
    surname, name, patronymic = full_name.split()
    return ' '.join((surname, f'{name[0]}.', f'{patronymic[0]}.'))

k = {key: fio(val) for key,val in k.items()}
print(k)
```